# React-router-dom v6 params

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

How do I create a route in react using react-router-dom v6?

Currently I'm trying:

```
<Route path="/registration:id" element={<Registration />} />
```

With a url of "http://localhost:3000/registration?code=testCode", I get the error:

```
No routes matched location "/registration?code=testCode
```

I've tried manipulating the route path in many different ways and the only way it works is if the path doesn't have the query part ":id".

Is this the new syntax for v6 or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 28):

React-router-dom generally only deals with the *path* part of the URL and not the querystring, and in RRDv6 there exists a [useSearchParams](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usesearchparams) hook you can use to access the querystring params. You won't specify any path match params though as this should be for matching the *path* part of the URL.

Given:

- path `"/registration?code=testCode"`
- `<Route path="/registration" element={<Registration />} />`

Example:

```
const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();
const code = searchParams.get('code'); // "testCode"
```

[image: Edit react-router-dom-v6-params]

Answer (score -1):

Put "/" after registration

```
<Route path="/registration/:id" element={<Registration />} />
```