# How to get query string value for different key using fetch react

Tags: reactjs

```
//hotels?country_id=searched_country_id
//hotels?city_id=searched_city_id
//hotels?hotel_id=searched_hotel_id


useEffect(() => {
  const idCategory = params.id;
  const idName = params.id;

  fetch(
    `http://10.58.5.162:8000/hotels?${idCategory}=${idName}`
     ,
    {
      method: 'GET',
    }
  )
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      setHotelList(data.message);
    });
}, []);
```

I want to make fetch for `country_id`, `city_id`, and `hotel_id` but until I get data, I do not know which one. It could be `country_id` or `city_id` or `hotel_id`, but not both. I do not know how to do it so I would appreciate any advice! Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you can find your detailed answer in here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35352638/how-to-get-parameter-value-from-query-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35352638/how-to-get-parameter-value-from-query-string)

Comment: which react-router version do you use?

Comment: Mine is version 6 !

Comment: until you get what data? params.id?

Comment: I get data like this: hotels?country_id=searched_country_id but here country_id could be city_id or hotel_id

Comment: @dlkhjs i updated my answer pls check below or you can check the demo working example here [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-dom-v6-params-forked-grc3y1?file=/src/App.js:0-1406)

Answer (score 0):

using react-route-v6 `useSearchParams` you can get it like here have demo example [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-dom-v6-params-forked-grc3y1?file=/src/App.js:0-1146)

```
import "./styles.css";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,
  Link,
  useSearchParams
} from "react-router-dom";

/**
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70043493/react-router-dom-v6-params
 */

const HotelsComponent = () => {
  const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();
  let queryParams = "";
  if (searchParams.get("country_id")) {
    queryParams = `country_id=${searchParams.get("country_id")}`;
  } else if (searchParams.get("city_id")) {
    queryParams = `city_id=${searchParams.get("city_id")}`;
  } else {
    queryParams = `hotel_id=${searchParams.get("hotel_id")}`;
  }

  return <div>country_id: {queryParams}</div>;
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/hotels?country_id=123455">
              /hotels?country_id=123455
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/hotels?city_id=123">/hotels?city_id=123</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/hotels?hotel_id=123">/hotels?hotel_id=123</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/hotels" element={<HotelsComponent />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```